# How do I see the correlation between a columns and all the others in a dataframe?

Tags: python

I have a pandas dataframe and I would like to see the correlation between the first columns and all the others. How can I do that in Python?

Answer (score 0):

simply:

```
df.corr()
```

it will display the corr between all columns of the dataframe df